# How do I update the value in the object in array (with nextjs api in mongodb database)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

my database is as below

```
 "_id":"xxxxxx",
      "owner": "yyy@hotmail.com",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "pid": 41,
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "pid": 42,
          "qty": 4
        }],
```

How can I change the qty value in products with pid value 41 in the nextjs api ?

api/cart

```
if(method === "PUT") {
    try {
    const updateResult = await DbScart.findOneAndUpdate(
    ???
    )
    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: updtprod });
    } catch(err) {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use update with [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
{products: {$elemMatch: {pid: 41}}},
{$set: {"products.$[item].qty": newValue}},
{arrayFilters: [{"item.pid": 41}]}
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xEZEe6XLDrU)